# Is there a way to add an item to a list inside a Panda's column using the index of another list?

Tags: python, pandas, string, list

I've been working with a `Panda DataFrame`, and I could use some advice with the following problem:

My `DataFrame` looks like this:

```
   OMA                        seq     Org               Score
0  A1        [ATG, AGA, ---, CTA]   Human       [000,000,111]      
1  A1        [ATG, AGG, ACT, CTA]   Bovin       [000,000,111]   
2  A1        [ATG, AGA, ---, CTA]   Mouse       [000,000,111]
3  B1        [ATG, TCG, TGC, ATG]   Human   [111,111,000,000]     
4  B1        [ATG, ---, TGC, GTC]   Bovin   [111,111,000,000]   
5  B1        [ATG, TCG, TGC, GTC]   Mouse   [111,111,000,000]
```

And here's my problem: the column `Score` comes from a different `DataFrame`, belonging only to `Human Org`, and its length matches de one of the `seq` list before the gaps (those are the `---`) were applied.
So, what I'm trying to do is to add an indicator (i.e `XXX`) in Score where there's a gap, following the index of `seq`.

Here's my desired output:

```
   OMA                        seq     Org               Score
0  A1        [ATG, AGA, ---, CTA]   Human   [000,000,XXX,111]  #Seq lenght is 3, score is 2, there    
1  A1        [ATG, AGG, ACT, CTA]   Bovin   [000,000,XXX,111]  #is a gap in seq[2] that is added!  
2  A1        [ATG, AGA, ---, CTA]   Mouse   [000,000,XXX,111]  #
3  B1        [ATG, TCG, TGC, ATG]   Human   [111,111,000,000]     
4  B1        [ATG, ---, TGC, GTC]   Bovin   [111,111,000,000]   
5  B1        [ATG, TCG, TGC, GTC]   Mouse   [111,111,000,000]
```

And, after that, I would like to compare the two columns and **only** get the items in `seq` that are equivalent to a `111` in `Score`, i.e:

```
   OMA                        seq     Org               Score     seq_Score
0  A1        [ATG, AGA, ---, CTA]   Human   [000,000,XXX,111]         [CTA]
1  A1        [ATG, AGG, ACT, CTA]   Bovin   [000,000,XXX,111]         [CTA]
2  A1        [ATG, AGA, ---, CTA]   Mouse   [000,000,XXX,111]         [CTA]
3  B1        [ATG, TCG, TGC, ATG]   Human   [111,111,000,000]     [ATG,TCG]
4  B1        [ATG, ---, TGC, GTC]   Bovin   [111,111,000,000]     [ATG,---]
5  B1        [ATG, TCG, TGC, GTC]   Mouse   [111,111,000,000]     [ATG,TCG]
```

EDIT: There are some `Human seq`'s that don't have a gap, I just edited the `DataFrame` to make it clearer.

Any help is weclome, and if I wasn't clear enough please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
score = []
for _, g in df.groupby("OMA"):
    idx = g.loc[g["Org"].eq("Human"), "seq"].iat[0].index("---")
    g.Score.apply(lambda x: x.insert(idx, "XXX"))
    score.extend(
        g.apply(
            lambda x: [a for a, b in zip(x["seq"], x["Score"]) if b == "111"],
            axis=1,
        )
    )

df["seq_Score"] = score
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  OMA                   seq    Org                 Score   seq_Score
0  A1  [ATG, AGA, ---, CTA]  Human  [000, 000, XXX, 111]       [CTA]
1  A1  [ATG, AGG, ACT, CTA]  Bovin  [000, 000, XXX, 111]       [CTA]
2  A1  [ATG, AGA, ---, CTA]  Mouse  [000, 000, XXX, 111]       [CTA]
3  B1  [ATG, TCG, TGC, ---]  Human  [111, 111, 000, XXX]  [ATG, TCG]
4  B1  [ATG, ---, TGC, GTC]  Bovin  [111, 111, 000, XXX]  [ATG, ---]
5  B1  [ATG, TCG, TGC, GTC]  Mouse  [111, 111, 000, XXX]  [ATG, TCG]
```

---

EDIT: To handle the case when `---` is not in Human `seq`:

```py
score = []
for _, g in df.groupby("OMA"):
    first_human = g.loc[g["Org"].eq("Human"), "seq"].iat[0]
    if "---" in first_human:
        idx = g.loc[g["Org"].eq("Human"), "seq"].iat[0].index("---")
        g.Score.apply(lambda x: x.insert(idx, "XXX"))

    score.extend(
        g.apply(
            lambda x: [a for a, b in zip(x["seq"], x["Score"]) if b == "111"],
            axis=1,
        )
    )

df["seq_Score"] = score
print(df)
```

Comment: This seems to work ok on the example! On the original, it does not work, and I identified the problem: there are some ```Human seq``` that don't have any gaps, so it trows the ```ValueError: '---' is not in list```.  Is there a way to fix this? Like adding a "pass"? Thanks a lot!!